# Sh command with -c option in unix

Tags: shell, unix, posix, sh

i am trying to run the below set of commands using sh -c

```
sh -c "
Dup_flag=`wc -l test.dat | awk '{print $1}'`;
user='test@domain.com';
text='Hi';
subject='Notification';
if [ $Dup_flag -eq 0 ];
then
  echo $Dup_flag | mailx -r $user -s $subject $user;
fi
"
```

it is not giving the desired result

when i run the same in a script

```
Dup_flag=`wc -l test.dat | awk '{print $1}'`
user='user@domain.com'
text='Hi'
subject='Notification'
if [ $Dup_flag -eq 8 ]
then
  echo $Dup_flag | mailx -r $user -s $subject $user
fi
```

it is giving the desired result

can some one help me where i am doing wrong here .i haven to run them with only sh -c

Thanks

Comment: What is the desired and undesired result, or at least the difference between them?  This could be helpful information.

Comment: The desired result is to send mail when the file has some records (typo error in if condition , the condition should be $dup_flag -ne 0)

Comment: Maby better on [Super User](http://superuser.com/tour)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first version fails because the double-quoted argument is processed by the shell that invokes `sh -c "…your script…"`.

That means that the `wc` and `awk` are run before the `sh -c` is invoked.  Also, the various variable references `$Dup_flag` etc are evaluated by the invoking shell, not by the invoked shell.

You'd need to use backslashes to escape the back-ticks and dollar signs.  Even if you changed to the `$(…)` notation, you'd still have to escape that `$`.

Or use single quotes around the `sh -c '…your script…'` and use double quotes where appropiate inside the script.

<sup>*I thought I'd added the 'Escapes' and 'Single quotes' sections before.  The submission process to SO glitched (paused); probably my internet connection at fault, but I seem to have closed the tab without noticing it was not successful.*</sup>

#### Escapes

```
sh -c "
Dup_flag=\`wc -l test.dat | awk '{print \$1}'\`;
user='test@domain.com';
subject='Notification'
if [ \$Dup_flag -eq 0 ]
then
  echo \$Dup_flag | mailx -r \$user -s \$subject \$user
fi
"
```

#### Single quotes

```
sh -c '
Dup_flag=`wc -l test.dat | awk "{print $1}"`
user="test@domain.com"
subject="Notification"
if [ "$Dup_flag" -eq 0 ]
then
  echo "$Dup_flag" | mailx -r "$user" -s "$subject" "$user"
fi
'
```

Note that the single-quoted version will make it much easier to have multi-word subject lines for the email, etc.

In both versions, I deleted `text` as it is unused.  The semicolons aren't necessary when the command is spread over multiple lines (so I removed them).  They'd be necessary if it was all flattened onto a single line.

---

> Actually, I need to run the mentioned commands in an Informatica command task which runs the commands as `sh -c " my script "`.

Ouch.  That adds a number of levels of possible confusion.  It could be that the Informatica code creates a shell command like this:

```
char *args[] = { "sh", "-c", your_string, 0 };
execvp(args[0], args);
```

In that case, my diagnosis of your problem is off the mark; nothing except the final shell interprets the contents of your string.

OTOH, they could use:

```
char buffer[4096];
snprintf(buffer, sizeof(buffer), "sh -c \"%s\"", your_string);
system(buffer);
```

In that case, the `system()` function runs a shell that in turn analyzes and runs the shell that actually runs your script.  My analysis then comes into effect.

There are likely other ways to achieve the job; they might have subtly different effects.

Comment: Thanks Jonathan for the explanation . actually the mentioned commands I need to run them in informatica command task which runs the commands as sh -c " my script " . I will post the results after making the changes suggested by you (backslash to $,')

Comment: it worked after escaping the $ and back-ticks   
sh -c "
Dup_flag=\`wc -l test.dat | awk '{print \$1}'\`
user='user@domain.com';
text='Hi';
subject='Notification';

if [ \$Dup_flag -eq 8 ]
then
  echo \$Dup_flag | mailx -r \$user -s \$subject \$user;
fi
"
Thanks Jonathan

Answer (score 1):

it worked after escaping the $ and back-ticks

```
sh -c "
Dup_flag=\`wc -l test.dat | awk '{print \$1}'\`
user='user@domain.com';
text='Hi';
subject='Notification';

if [ \$Dup_flag -eq 8 ]
then
  echo \$Dup_flag | mailx -r \$user -s \$subject \$user;
fi
"
```

Thanks Jonathan